# Regular expression in distinct texts

Tags: regex

I have two patterns to use a regular expression. In the first one, I have this pattern and I can catch the word.

With this regex:

```
referente[,;]*\s\S\s(.+)\.\sOnde
```

> O COORDENADOR-GERAL DE GESTÃO DE PESSOAS DO MINISTÉRIO DOS TRANSPORTES, PORTOS E AVIAÇÃO CIVIL, no uso das atribuições que lhe foram subdelegadas pela Portaria/SAAD nº. 202, art. 1°, inciso VII, de 08 de outubro de 2010, publicada no Diário Oficial da União, de 11 de outubro de 2010, resolve:
>   Retificar a Portaria COGEP-MT nº 3394, de 30 de novembro de 2016, publicada no Diário Oficial da União, Seção 2, página 55, de 13 de dezembro de 2016, **referente à MARIA ALIXANDRINA COSTA REIS. Onde** se lê "MARIA AUXILIADORA COSTA REIS"; Leia-se "MARIA ALIXANDRINA COSTA REIS.(Processo SEI: 50000.124582/2016-62) BA.

I need to take the name in another pattern.

> O COORDENADOR-GERAL DE GESTÃO DE PESSOAS DO MINISTÉRIO DOS
>   TRANSPORTES, PORTOS E AVIAÇÃO CIVIL, no uso das atribuições que lhe
>   foram subdelegadas pela Portaria/SAAD nº. 202, art.1º, inciso VII, de
>   08 de outubro de 2010, publicada no Diário Oficial da União, de 11 de
>   outubro de 2010, resolve: Conceder Pensão Temporária, nos termos do
>   artigo 215 e 217, inciso II, alínea "a" da Lei nº 8.112/1990, **à
>   ELIANE RIBEIRO MENESES**, filha inválida do ex-servidor ASTOLFO
>   MENEZES, matrícula SIAPE nº. 0783182, do Quadro Permanente deste
>   Ministério, falecido na inatividade em 05 de agosto de 1997, cuja cota
>   parte equivale a 100% (cem por cento) do valor correspondente à
>   remuneração decorrente do cargo de Artífice de Mecânica (NI), Classe
>   "A", Padrão "III", com vigência partir do momento da Publicação da
>   Portaria de Concessão e efeitos financeiros a partir de 30 de maio de
>   2015, data do falecimento da viúva. (Processo SEI nº
>   50000.019342/2016-47) - MG.

I need to take the bold word too, in the same regex. How can I modify this regex?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: pure regex https://regex101.com/

Comment: Would this be ok? ↓

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to match/embolden the trailing punctuation and `Onde`/`Where` substring.

I would recommend this pattern to optionally match `referente` then the `à` then the all-caps words to follow.  There are no capture groups, just replace the fullstring with the emboldened fullstring.

(I don't use nsregularexpression, so let me know if something is simply not right.)

```
/(?:referente )?à [A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)*/u
```

The unicode flag is to accommodate the accented letters that will be encountered.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gKhe5M/1)

p.s. In your "solution" you are incorporating `[,;]*` but that doesn't get represented in your sample strings, so I left it out.  Reducing the total number of parenthetical groups delivers improved pattern efficiency -- that is why I use just two non-capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following regex to match the 2 bold parts of your examples:

```
(à\sELIANE\s\w+\s\w+SES)|(referente[,;]*\s\S\s.+\.\sOnde)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply, but the name in the bold is dinamic.

Comment: do you mean the part in upper case is dynamic? Do you have more information? like how many words to fetch or a list of words to look in? If not it will be difficult to build a regex that fulfill your requirements!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is `([,;]*)*\sà\s((\w+\s)+\w+)[\.,]`